# Could not find gem 'change_final' in any of the gem sources listed in your remote: Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rubygems

I have created a gem that is working locally but when I try to push my web app to heroku master I get the error in the title. I dont know why it is occurring as It is in my gem file and I have ran bundle install. this is my gemfie:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.6.5'

gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.1.1'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'rails_admin', '~> 2.0'
gem 'weight'
gem 'excon'
gem 'rails-observers'
gem "sinatra"
gem "pundit"
gem 'pry', group: :development
gem 'unit_converter'
gem 'change_final'
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.2', '>= 6.0.2.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 4.1'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.0'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'
gem 'devise'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

This is my gemfile.lock file

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (6.0.2.2)
      actionpack (= 6.0.2.2)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.6.1)
    actionmailbox (6.0.2.2)
      actionpack (= 6.0.2.2)
      activejob (= 6.0.2.2)
      activerecord (= 6.0.2.2)
      activestorage (= 6.0.2.2)
      activesupport (= 6.0.2.2)
      mail (>= 2.7.1)
    actionmailer (6.0.2.2)
      actionpack (= 6.0.2.2)
      actionview (= 6.0.2.2)
      activejob (= 6.0.2.2)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (6.0.2.2)
      actionview (= 6.0.2.2)
      activesupport (= 6.0.2.2)
      rack (~> 2.0, >= 2.0.8)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.2.0)
    actiontext (6.0.2.2)
      actionpack (= 6.0.2.2)
      activerecord (= 6.0.2.2)
      activestorage (= 6.0.2.2)
      activesupport (= 6.0.2.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.8.5)
    actionview (6.0.2.2)
      activesupport (= 6.0.2.2)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubi (~> 1.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.1, >= 1.2.0)
    activejob (6.0.2.2)
      activesupport (= 6.0.2.2)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (6.0.2.2)
      activesupport (= 6.0.2.2)
    activemodel-serializers-xml (1.0.2)
      activemodel (> 5.x)
      activesupport (> 5.x)
      builder (~> 3.1)
    activerecord (6.0.2.2)
      activemodel (= 6.0.2.2)
      activesupport (= 6.0.2.2)
    activestorage (6.0.2.2)
      actionpack (= 6.0.2.2)
      activejob (= 6.0.2.2)
      activerecord (= 6.0.2.2)
      marcel (~> 0.3.1)
    activesupport (6.0.2.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (>= 0.7, < 2)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
      zeitwerk (~> 2.2)
    addressable (2.7.0)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 5.0)
    autoprefixer-rails (9.7.5)
      execjs
    bcrypt (3.1.13)
    bindex (0.8.1)
    bootsnap (1.4.6)
      msgpack (~> 1.0)
    bootstrap (4.1.3)
      autoprefixer-rails (>= 6.0.3)
      popper_js (>= 1.12.9, < 2)
      sass (>= 3.5.2)
    builder (3.2.4)
    byebug (11.1.1)
    capybara (3.31.0)
      addressable
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.3)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
      rack (>= 1.6.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      regexp_parser (~> 1.5)
      xpath (~> 3.2)
    change_final (0.0.0)
    childprocess (3.0.0)
    coderay (1.1.2)
    concurrent-ruby (1.1.6)
    crass (1.0.6)
    devise (4.7.1)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 4.1.0)
      responders
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    erubi (1.9.0)
    excon (0.73.0)
    execjs (2.7.0)
    ffi (1.12.2-x64-mingw32)
    globalid (0.4.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    haml (5.1.2)
      temple (>= 0.8.0)
      tilt
    i18n (1.8.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    jbuilder (2.10.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.0.0)
    jquery-rails (4.3.5)
      rails-dom-testing (>= 1, < 3)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    jquery-ui-rails (6.0.1)
      railties (>= 3.2.16)
    kaminari (1.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.1.0)
      kaminari-actionview (= 1.2.0)
      kaminari-activerecord (= 1.2.0)
      kaminari-core (= 1.2.0)
    kaminari-actionview (1.2.0)
      actionview
      kaminari-core (= 1.2.0)
    kaminari-activerecord (1.2.0)
      activerecord
      kaminari-core (= 1.2.0)
    kaminari-core (1.2.0)
    loofah (2.4.0)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.7.1)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
    marcel (0.3.3)
      mimemagic (~> 0.3.2)
    method_source (1.0.0)
    mimemagic (0.3.4)
    mini_mime (1.0.2)
    mini_portile2 (2.4.0)
    minitest (5.14.0)
    msgpack (1.3.3-x64-mingw32)
    mustermann (1.1.1)
      ruby2_keywords (~> 0.0.1)
    nested_form (0.3.2)
    nio4r (2.5.2)
    nokogiri (1.10.9-x64-mingw32)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.4.0)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    pg (1.2.3-x64-mingw32)
    popper_js (1.16.0)
    pry (0.13.0)
      coderay (~> 1.1)
      method_source (~> 1.0)
    public_suffix (4.0.3)
    puma (4.3.3)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
    pundit (2.1.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    rack (2.2.2)
    rack-pjax (1.1.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.5)
      rack (>= 1.1)
    rack-protection (2.0.8.1)
      rack
    rack-proxy (0.6.5)
      rack
    rack-test (1.1.0)
      rack (>= 1.0, < 3)
    rails (6.0.2.2)
      actioncable (= 6.0.2.2)
      actionmailbox (= 6.0.2.2)
      actionmailer (= 6.0.2.2)
      actionpack (= 6.0.2.2)
      actiontext (= 6.0.2.2)
      actionview (= 6.0.2.2)
      activejob (= 6.0.2.2)
      activemodel (= 6.0.2.2)
      activerecord (= 6.0.2.2)
      activestorage (= 6.0.2.2)
      activesupport (= 6.0.2.2)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0)
      railties (= 6.0.2.2)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.3.0)
      loofah (~> 2.3)
    rails-observers (0.1.5)
      activemodel (>= 4.0)
    rails_12factor (0.0.3)
      rails_serve_static_assets
      rails_stdout_logging
    rails_admin (2.0.2)
      activemodel-serializers-xml (>= 1.0)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      haml (>= 4.0, < 6)
      jquery-rails (>= 3.0, < 5)
      jquery-ui-rails (>= 5.0, < 7)
      kaminari (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
      nested_form (~> 0.3)
      rack-pjax (>= 0.7)
      rails (>= 5.0, < 7)
      remotipart (~> 1.3)
      sassc-rails (>= 1.3, < 3)
    rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.5)
    rails_stdout_logging (0.0.5)
    railties (6.0.2.2)
      actionpack (= 6.0.2.2)
      activesupport (= 6.0.2.2)
      method_source
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.20.3, < 2.0)
    rake (13.0.1)
    rb-fsevent (0.10.3)
    rb-inotify (0.10.1)
      ffi (~> 1.0)
    regexp_parser (1.7.0)
    remotipart (1.4.4)
    responders (3.0.0)
      actionpack (>= 5.0)
      railties (>= 5.0)
    ruby2_keywords (0.0.2)
    rubyzip (2.3.0)
    sass (3.7.4)
      sass-listen (~> 4.0.0)
    sass-listen (4.0.0)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
    sass-rails (6.0.0)
      sassc-rails (~> 2.1, >= 2.1.1)
    sassc (2.2.1-x64-mingw32)
      ffi (~> 1.9)
    sassc-rails (2.1.2)
      railties (>= 4.0.0)
      sassc (>= 2.0)
      sprockets (> 3.0)
      sprockets-rails
      tilt
    selenium-webdriver (3.142.7)
      childprocess (>= 0.5, < 4.0)
      rubyzip (>= 1.2.2)
    sinatra (2.0.8.1)
      mustermann (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 2.0)
      rack-protection (= 2.0.8.1)
      tilt (~> 2.0)
    sprockets (4.0.0)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.2.1)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    sqlite3 (1.4.2)
    temple (0.8.2)
    thor (1.0.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.6)
    tilt (2.0.10)
    turbolinks (5.2.1)
      turbolinks-source (~> 5.2)
    turbolinks-source (5.2.0)
    tzinfo (1.2.6)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    tzinfo-data (1.2019.3)
      tzinfo (>= 1.0.0)
    unit_converter (0.0.0)
    warden (1.2.8)
      rack (>= 2.0.6)
    web-console (4.0.1)
      actionview (>= 6.0.0)
      activemodel (>= 6.0.0)
      bindex (>= 0.4.0)
      railties (>= 6.0.0)
    webdrivers (4.2.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6)
      rubyzip (>= 1.3.0)
      selenium-webdriver (>= 3.0, < 4.0)
    webpacker (4.2.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2)
      rack-proxy (>= 0.6.1)
      railties (>= 4.2)
    websocket-driver (0.7.1)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.4)
    weight (1.0.0)
    xpath (3.2.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
    zeitwerk (2.3.0)

PLATFORMS
  x64-mingw32

DEPENDENCIES
  bootsnap (>= 1.4.2)
  bootstrap (~> 4.1.1)
  byebug
  capybara (>= 2.15)
  change_final
  devise
  excon
  jbuilder (~> 2.7)
  jquery-rails
  pg
  pry
  puma (~> 4.1)
  pundit
  rails (~> 6.0.2, >= 6.0.2.1)
  rails-observers
  rails_12factor
  rails_admin (~> 2.0)
  sass-rails (>= 6)
  selenium-webdriver
  sinatra
  sqlite3
  turbolinks (~> 5)
  tzinfo-data
  unit_converter
  web-console (>= 3.3.0)
  webdrivers
  webpacker (~> 4.0)
  weight

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.6.5p114

BUNDLED WITH
   2.1.4
```

The gem that is giving me the error is the one I created : gem 'change_final'. I have created one previously and didnt get this error. I have been searching for a while now but still not sure what is happening. Any suggestions? 
Error Message

```
remote:        Could not find gem 'change_final' in any of the gem sources listed in your
remote:        Gemfile.
remote:
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to thawing-reaches-56643.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/thawing-reaches-56643.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/thawing-reaches-56643.git'
```

Comment: I suspect your error is due to heroku not able to find your gem location in git. 

When you say "I have created one previously" -- a different gem or a version of the `change_final` gem? Did you not update the version number?

Comment: I created  one in the same project which is a version of change_final and they are both version 0.0.0. does that matter?

Comment: When you say "created one" -- I do not know if you mean a different gem or the first version of `change_final`.

However, I would look to see how you can get Heroku to know about *your* custom gem. Where it lives...

Comment: I mean that i developed one and built it then installed it. I have created 2 different gems but with the same functionality as then first one was giving my a typeerror

Comment: Does this post answer your question?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29156296/unable-to-push-a-custom-gem-to-heroku-master

Comment: yeah that fixed it. thanks so much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to push a custom gem to heroku master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29156296/unable-to-push-a-custom-gem-to-heroku-master)